# Broken Shimano FD-R453

Tags: shimano, derailleur, replacement

I have a Shimano FD-R453 front derailleur that needs replacing. 50t and bottom pull with a 31.8 clamp.  There are three gears in the front and 9 gears in the back.  Could somebody help me with getting something similar as they don't make these anymore.

Comment: I did a quick search for Shimano 453 and 450 series. There was a 6 speed MTB group but no 9 speed. Can you check the group set series and provide us either the name? Was this road or MTB? Aprox how old is the bike?

Comment: Road Bike (Specialized).  The Bike is 7 years old, and bought it new.  Seems like they had a lot of trouble with the FD-R453.

Comment: Avid is the name on the hand controls on handlebars, does that help?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like The FD-R453 is a non-series (i.e. it does not get the 'Tiagra', '105' etc label) component. I believe it's roughly equivalent to Tiagra in quality though.

Any Shimano 3x9 front derailleur is going to work, Tiagra 4500 series - which is not current but is probably available, Sora 3400 or 3500 series also. The Sora FD-3030-B looks right.

Comment: @jimmyg. Sora is Shimano's dedicated 9-speed groupset. For a triple front the latest selections are FD-3503, FD-3403, FD-3030.  The 3030 mech is designed for a 50t chainwheel.  Thought I'd offer that as you referenced "50t" in your question, which i assumed that to mean what you have now.